# C library cannot be linked when main.rs and lib.rs coexist

Tags: rust, linker, ffi

## Basic setup

A simple C function that is called from Rust via FFI, and a static library (Windows) that is linked in build.rs.

```c
// api.c

int increment(int value) {
    return value + 1;
}
```

```rust
// main.rs

extern {
    fn increment(value: i32) -> i32;
}

fn main() {
    let num = unsafe { increment(4) };
    println!("The incremented number is {}", num);
}
```

```rust
// build.rs

fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=src/ffi");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=api");
}
```

With this directory structure:

```
Cargo.toml
Cargo.lock
build.rs
src
+-- main.rs
+-- ffi
    +-- api.c
    +-- api.lib
```

Cargo.toml has nothing but a crate name, version, author and Rust edition.

So far, this works perfectly, and "The incremented number is 5" is printed as expected.

---

## The problem

Now I add an **empty** `lib.rs` file, so I can use my crate as both a library and a binary:

```
Cargo.toml
Cargo.lock
build.rs
src
+-- lib.rs     <-- NEW
+-- main.rs
+-- ffi
    +-- api.c
    +-- api.lib
```

I do not change Cargo.toml.
This alone makes the link step fail (MSVC linker):

> error LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol "increment" referenced in function "_ZN16my_crate4main17h887bd80180495b7eE"

The error persists even if I explicitly specify the presence of both a library and binary in Cargo.toml and run using `cargo run --bin my_main`:

```
[lib]
name = "my_lib"
path = "src/lib.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "my_main"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

I also made sure that `build.rs` is still executed in the binary case, by letting it panic to abort the build.

I'm aware that I *could* solve it by splitting the crate, but I'd like to understand what exactly happens. So:

---

**Why does the presence of an empty `lib.rs` cause the linker to fail?**
**And is there a way to make it succeed, in a single crate?**

Comment: I don't specifically know your issue, but in the past when I wanted both a bin and a lib in the same crate I had to change the crate to be a lib (src/lib.rs) with no src/main.rs, and add binaries to it that used the lib (src/bin/bin1.rs, src/bin/bin2.rs, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the presence of both a binary and a Rust library in a single crate, Rust statically links the binary against the Rust library itself, as if the library were any other external crate (e.g. from crates.io). I assume to prevent errors due to duplicate symbols, or possibly just to avoid code bloat or extra work, it appears to avoid linking any external artifacts directly against the binary, and does not make an effort to determine if the code in question is even available in `lib.rs` before making this judgment. Normally this happens in the background without you noticing (i.e. it's doing this to the Rust standard library, your system standard libraries, and external crates as well for everything you compile), but when you introduce custom FFI dependencies it becomes obvious.

If you change your `lib.rs` to

```rust
extern {
    pub fn increment(value: i32) -> i32;
}
```

And your `main.rs` to

```rust
fn main() {
    let num = unsafe { libname::increment(4) };
    println!("The incremented number is {}", num);
}
```

Where `libname` is either the name of your library as listed in `Cargo.toml` or the project name if that's not specificed, it will compile and run properly. Indeed, this follows no matter how complex you get. You can bury the FFI function a million modules deep and include it from wherever, but it will fail with the same error if you reference a definition of an `extern "C"` function without going through the master library crate first.

I don't know if there's any way (in `build.rs` or otherwise) to *insist* that Rust statically links a library either twice against the two different targets, or else only against the binary itself, but if there is it's not well documented or obvious.

That said, in most cases this is unlikely to be a problem, since if you're making your functionality usable as a library, it's likely you'll have the common code, including FFI, in there anyway. It could conceivably be an issue if you have a C dependency (e.g. for device access) that only makes sense in the binary, but I think that case is rare enough it's reasonable to force you to split the crates using workspaces if that's your specific situation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Are you sure the example you mentioned works? If I move the `extern { pub fn increment(...) }` to `lib.rs` and call it as `unsafe { mylib::increment(4) }` from `main.rs`, the linker error persists. Do I need special Cargo.toml entries? I just have `[lib] name = "mylib"`, nothing about `[[bin]]` or so.

Comment: Full disclaimer, I did this by using the `cc` crate in `build.rs` to compile the C file instead of using a prebuilt lib because I didn't have one on hand, my best guess is there's some differences in that setup-wise? I tested this on my computer but the `cc` instead of prebuilt lib was the only difference. My `Cargo.toml` didn't have a `[lib]` section, I was just letting it auto-generate based on the crate name.

Comment: By the way, you don't have something like `mod mylib;` in your main.rs, right? Because that would cause the error.

Comment: You're actually right. I think there was a problem with caching, after deleting `target` it worked. It is indeed moving the `extern` block to `lib.rs` which fixes the linking. Thanks a lot for your help!